# testcase is getting failed in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium

Hi I am trying to run a test case in chrome browser and that test case is getting passed in firefox but it is getting failed in chrome browser
.this is the selenium code

```
_driver.findElement(By.linkText("Expence_Link")).click();;
_driver.findElement(By.id("searchButton")).click();
_driver.findElement(By.id("descriptionInput")).sendKeys("Description");
_driver.findElement(By.id("saveAndNextExpenseButton")).click();
```

and this is the html code

```
<input id="searchButton" class="formSubmit" type="button" value="Search" tabindex="3">
<a href="https://xyz/Collaborate?pbId=77501&sB=yat93&op=AddProjectBudgetActualExpense">Expence_Link</a>
<input id="descriptionInput" name="pre.projectBudgetActualExpense.description.value" value="" size="30" style="width:300px" tabindex="4" maxlength="665">
<input id="saveAndNextExpenseButton" class="formSubmit" type="button" onclick="onSaveAndNextExpenseButtonClick(); return false;" value="Save & Next Actual" tabindex="13">
```

and the error it is showing is

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
(Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING:     The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.02 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions     /no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'ADMINIB-BHMHBF7', ip: '9.109.111.10', os.name: 'Windows 7',     os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome=       {userDataDir=C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4692_20611},     takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=39.0.2171.95,    platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,     acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,     webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,     cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 03b44e91e408e56380c5d261b07cc97f
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:357)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
at uiactions.Wrappers.SendKeys(Wrappers.java:254)
at test.object.ExpencePage_Object.Description_Fn(ExpencePage_Object.java:43)
at test.function.ExpencePage_Function.Expence_Page_Test(ExpencePage_Function.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I am unable to the send keys into the textbox with id 'descriptionInput' i tried out with name, xpath, cssSelector but nothing is working. clicking expence link and search button are working fine in chrome

please help me to get out of this issue
thanks in advance

Comment: What Error/Exception are you getting ?

Comment: Which of the findElement statements is it failing on?

Comment: For which element are you getting the **NoSuchElementException**? Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Subh it is showing no such element

Comment: @user3819070: I can see that. But, please add for which element it is showing that exception for. You must be getting the Stacktrace in your console.. Please add that. Because just stating a partial  exception won't help us track the problem in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the Chrome driver might not like the unencoded `&` you've used in the saveAndNextExpenseButton input value. Best encode that in any case (`&amp;`).

Comment: I am sorry. It is still unclear. Anyways, tell me when executing, which step of the above doesn't run? I mean, is the **Expence_Link not getting clicked** or **searchButton not getting clicked** or **descriptionInput is not filled with "Description"** or **saveAndNextExpenseButton is not getting clicked**?

Comment: I am unable to the send keys into the textbox with id 'descriptionInput' i tried out with name, xpath, cssSelector but nothing is working. clicking expence link and search button are working fine in chrome

Comment: and one more thing I have to say except this testcase all the other test cases are working fine with chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) like below to wait for the visibility of the field and then send values to it:

```
//Waiting for 10 seconds for the presence of the description field and then entering text 'Description'
try{
    WebElement input_desc = new WebDriverWait(_driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("descriptionInput")));
    input_desc.clear();
    input_desc.sendKeys("Description");
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Description field wasn't found. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Or else increase the [Implict wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) to 10 seconds:

```
_driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```